# Trying to making an insert into in a sql file in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

Im just trying to put some insert into on a sql file to import somewhere sql database, because i got an error when the register exists, so i would like to make nothing (Do not insert) if the register exists, for this reason i have tried with

```
INSERT INTO menu VALUES('Arsenal FC','?team=arsenal fc')
ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE '*already inserted*';
```

or `IF NO EXISTS INSERT INTO menu Values('Arsenal FC','?team=arsenal fc');`

I also have heared about on duplicate key update, but i dont want to update just want to not insert when exists.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO menu VALUES('Arsenal FC','?team=arsenal fc');
```

As documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore your all existing data, then there are two most accepted ways.

1. using **INSERT IGNORE** like

   INSERT IGNORE INTO menu VALUES('Arsenal FC','?team=arsenal fc');
2. Using '**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**' like

   INSERT INTO menu VALUES('Arsenal FC','?team=arsenal fc') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE key=key

   //note : i am supposing key is your unique or primary key constraint.

But i would suggest you to go with second way that is **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** because using **INSERT IGNORE**  ignores ALL errors (ie its a sloppy global ignore).  The row won't actually be inserted if it results in a duplicate key. But the statement won't generate an error. It generates a warning instead. And most importantly if you don't have any key constraint on your table then you need to alter your table with unique or primary key.